# How to send value with react-navigation in static filed?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen set a `<Switch />` in header by using `react navigation`.

I know how to get `this.state` value from outside function by  `this.props.navigation.setParams`.

But I don't know how to send the `<Switch />` value to outside function.

I try it with the code `onValueChange={value => params.handleThis(value)}`

but in my case `handleThis` is `key-value`, it can't get the value obviously.

`this.props.navigation.setParams({
   handleThis: this.changeSwitch
 });`

How to send `<Switch />` onChange value to outside function ?

Here is my code:

```
      static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
        return {
          title: 'Title',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: ColorSetting.headerColor,
            elevation: null,
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: '300',
            fontFamily: 'FFF Tusj',
            fontSize: 18
          },
          headerRight:
            <View style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>
              <Switch
                onValueChange={value => params.handleThis()}
                value={params.switchOn}
                onTintColor='#444444'
                tintColor='#444444'
              />
            </View>,
        };
      };

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          switchOn: false
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({
          handleThis: this.changeSwitch
        });
      }

  changeSwitch = () => {
    const { switchOn, titleVersion } = this.state;

    this.props.navigation.setParams({ switchOn: !switchOn });
    this.setState({ switchOn: !switchOn });
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so the issue here is that you don't know get the `<Switch>` value in `changeSwitch`? is that `<Switch>`the the one that you import from `react-native`?

Comment: Not at all, my issue is I can't use `this.setState` in `onValueChange`. It won't work if I use `onValueChange={value => this.setState({ switchOn: value })}`.  Because `<Switch />` is  in static field not in class component.

Comment: yeah you cannot access `this` in a static method, but you can achieve the same using `params.handleThis`, can't you? Are you getting any error? Are you not getting the value there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `params.handleThis` as the handler, there is no need for an inline function.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
  return {
    title: 'SO Question',
    headerStyle: {
      elevation: null,
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontFamily: 'FFF Tusj',
      fontSize: 18
    },
    headerRight:
      <View style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>
        <Switch
          onValueChange={params.handleThis}
          value={params.switchOn}
          onTintColor='#444444'
          tintColor='#444444'
        />
      </View>,
  };
};
```

after that `changeSwitch` will receive the new value as the first parameter.

```
changeSwitch = (switchOn) => {   
  this.props.navigation.setParams({ switchOn });
  this.setState({ switchOn });
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://snack.expo.io/HJti2B_nm)

Comment: I make it become more complicated, I know how to handle it now, your answer is really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks @QoP! I would also suggest using `navigation.getParam(paramName, optionalDefaultValue)` instead of destructuring `navigation.state`.